# What to return as default if the "if criteria" is not met? Overloading subscript operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm overloading the subscript operator, that given a name will search through the list and if it finds the name it will change the number of that person. The problem is what to do if the person is not found.

I get the warning `control reaches end of non-void function`but I don't know what the function should return as default.

```
string& List::operator[](string name)
{
    //loop through the list and see if the name exists
    for(int i = 0; i < nr_entries; i++)
    {
        //if it does, return the address for it
        if(listEntries[i].getName() == name)
            return listEntries[i].changeNr();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are using the wrong container type for `listEntries`, instead of using an array (which I think you are using) consider using an [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which will incidentally might help you solve this problem too.

Comment: Oh, and the answer to your problem also depends ***a lot*** on what the `changeNr` function returns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should re-think your design. It seems to me that the indexing operator isn't really the correct method here, instead the user of your class is *searching* for something, and expect the result to reflect if the item the user was looking for was found or not.

So to begin with you should probably change from using the indexing operator to a normal member function with an appropriate name, something including the word "search" or "find".

You should also think a little more about what you want to return. You call a function named `changeNr` to return a string. This doesn't really makes sense to me, the word "change" implies that you want to change something, and "nr"  implies a number. So by just seeing the name `changeNr` I would expect the function to change a a number, not return a string. Maybe it *getting* a change number? So why not rename it to `getChangeNr`? But then the "number" bit is still lingering, maybe it should really return a number, in which case your search function *also* should return a number? And in that case if the element is not found you can simply return a number that can never exist (`-1`, `INT_MAX`, etc).

If the function really *should* return a string, then by not using the indexing operator anymore, why not simply return a simple `std::string` object instead of a reference? And if the user should be able to modify the string, you might consider the function to return a pointer (or reference) to the complete structure instead.

If you really want to return a reference to a string, then if the element was not found return a static member variable and instruct the user through the documentation that the user *must* check if the returned reference is the same as this static member variable to see if it's the same.

You could of course throw an exception if the element was not found, but this should really be reserved for exceptional cases. If it's going to be commonplace that the element is not found, then that's not exceptional, and you should try to avoid exceptions.

Finally, whatever you decide to do, the important thing you need to think about is *documentation*! No matter which way you go, if the function is not well-documented the user will not know what it does, and what to expect. And that "user" will include *you* is a year or two. Document what arguments the function take, and what values it might return, then document *why* it returns what it does because that's more important than how it does it (the "how" can be seen through the code).

Comment: The problem is we have to use arrays and overload operator[ ]. 
To clairify the list contains "Entries" which contain of 2 strings.
 One called name for the "name" and one "phone_nr" which contains the persons phone number. 

I made some changes to the return line so that .changeNr() now only is .phone_nr.

When someone writes ["firstname lastname"] = "0700111111 "; If the person exists the phonenumber of that person will change.

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities are endless, but my first thought would be to return a reference to a zero-length string or a string such as "". The caller should check the return value against those possibilities. Note that whatever default string is chosen, it probably should be declared `static` so that it won't go out of scope when your function returns and pops the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw an exception, you could change the return type to a string * and return a null pointer, or you could add an entry and return the new string.

That last one is what std::map does, for example.

But really you should think about how much you want to overload the [] operator, because none of the above are really going to be what you want and the clever-looking [] syntax you get is really not that important.